# How to design nosql database(dynamodb) schema in my situation

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am using aws dynamodb.

Let's say I have a slideshow gallery like below.
There are only 3 columns in my Table "Banners" which are id, createAt and url.
[image]

I can use upload button to upload photo.
When I press upload, 2 api will be called.

The first one is to create photo and store it at aws s3 bucket and then return the url, and the second one is used to store the url in Table "Banner".

Now I've come up a new design as below.
[image]

Every time I upload photo, it will show in "inactive banner".
The "Active Banner" will be shown in the slideshow at the top.
I can drag and drop the photo from "inactive banner" to "active banner" and vice versa.
Also, the order inside "active banner" can be changed by dragging to different position.
Every time I make changes, I need to click save to call api(PATCH/PUT) and make it work.

I have a few questions for the design.
1.Do I need to add more column in my dynamodb or new table? If yes, what should I do?
2.When I create/update banner, what actions should I do? I am not sure how to make it work by make http request.

Answer (score 1):

As it is one-to-one data ; so need to create multiple tables. Simple design would be to add two more columns in your table :

```
boolean activeOrInactive
int order
```

whenever you create banner; u would continue doing whatever u are right now along with default values of these two new columns also. During update banner; u will just update those values.